# Combine 2 php arrays?

Tags: php, arrays

How can I combine these 2 array?

```
$array1 = array("gif" => "gif", "jpg" => "jpeg", "jpeg" => "jpeg", "png" =>"png");
$array2 = array("gif" => "0", "jpg" => "90", "jpeg" => "90", "png" => "8");
```

I tried

```
$array1 = array("gif" => "gif" => "0", "jpg" => "jpeg" => "90", "jpeg" => "jpeg" => "90", "png" =>"png" => "8");
```

But of course it didn't work so any help?

Comment: can you explain what exactly you'd like to achieve? I'm *very* confused by your example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to make more sense:

```
$arr = array("gif" => array("extension" => "gif", "size" => "90"),
             "jpg" => array("extension" => "jpeg", "size" => "120")

               ...
              );

echo "Extension: " . $arr['gif']['extension'] . " Size or whatever: " . $arr['gif']['size'];
```

To loop over it:

```
foreach($arr as $key => $val) {
    echo "Image Type: $key, Extension: " . $val['extension'] . ", Size: " . $val['size'];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two values for each key. Create a sub-array for each key with more than one value:

```
$ar1 = array( 'key' => array('key1','key2') );
```

Answer (score 1):

To build on my previous answer, you're better of using to paralell arrays:

```
$validTypes = array("gif" => "gif", "jpg" => "jpeg", "jpeg" => "jpeg", "png" => "png");
$quality = array("gif" => 0, "jpg" => 90, "jpeg" => 90, "png" => "png");
if (!array_key_exists($image_type, $validTypes)) {
    trigger_error("Not a valid image type", E_USER_WARNING);
    return NULL;
}

// ...

$inFunc = "imagecreatefrom" . $validTypes[$image_type];
$outFunc = "image" . $validTypes[$image_type];

// ...

$outFunc($image, $source_file, $quality[$image_type]);
```

karim's answer is also fine, though. Just a matter of preference.

Comment: thanks, I ended up doing the 2 arrays, things usually come to my head right after I hit the submit button on a question

Answer (score 1):

```
$array1 = array("gif" => "gif", "jpg" => "jpeg", "jpeg" => "jpeg", "png" =>"png");
$array2 = array("gif" => "0", "jpg" => "90", "jpeg" => "90", "png" => "8");
$finalarray = (array_merge_recursive($array1,$array2));
```

the structure of $finalarray is:

```
Array
(
[gif] => Array
    (
        [0] => gif
        [1] => 0
    )

[jpg] => Array
    (
        [0] => jpeg
        [1] => 90
    )

[jpeg] => Array
    (
        [0] => jpeg
        [1] => 90
    )

[png] => Array
    (
        [0] => png
        [1] => 8
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure how you want to 'combine' them.  Im going to assume you want each key from the 1st array to map to a value in the 2nd

```
 foreach($array1 as $k=>$v)
 {
   $a3[$k] = $array2[$v]
 }
```

gives you

```
  $a3 = array('gif'=>'0', 'jpg'=>'90', 'jpeg'=>'90', 'png'=>'8');
```

But that is the same as array2.
Maybe

```
 foreach($array1 as $k=>$v)
 {
   $a3[$k] = array($array1[$k],$array2[$k]);
 }
```

gives

```
 $a3 = array('gif'=>array('gif',0),'jpg'=>array('jpeg',90)...)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised that none of the answers refer you to the following which could essentially be described as ["everything you ever wanted to know about PHP arrays but were afraid to ask"](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php)